Forward Class Declaration in Python in a Dictionary
This is a question that has been debated many times in this forum. There is however a case that i have not seen a good way to solve.
from __future__ import annotations

class ClassA:
    pass

class ClassC:
    c : ClassB
    children : dict = {'A': ClassA, 'B': ClassB}

class ClassB:
    pass

Interesting is that the statement c : ClassB works fine, but reference to ClassB in the Dictionary generates the error:
NameError: name 'ClassB' is not defined.
Is there a way to make this code work?

from __future__ import annotations only impacts forward type declarations. You actually need ClassB to exist to put it in the dictionary as a value. If you really must declare classes in that order, you'd have to have a line ClassC.children['B'] = ClassB after declaring ClassB.
